# Error when trying to reindex

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, error, reindex

I am currently running Magento 2.1.7 and imported data from Magento 1.8.0. The process went smoothly but after installing some extensions, it appears that some of the reindex tables have been deleted. This is the message I get when trying to reindex:

```
Table design_config_dummy_cl does not exist
Table customer_dummy_cl does not exist
Table catalog_category_product_cl does not exist
Table catalog_product_category_cl does not exist
Table catalog_product_price_cl does not exist
Table catalog_product_attribute_cl does not exist
Table cataloginventory_stock_cl does not exist
Table catalogrule_rule_cl does not exist
Table catalogrule_product_cl does not exist
Table catalogsearch_fulltext_cl does not exist
Search Spell-Correction index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
```

Even after using the reset function then reindexing, the process is stuck:

```
Design Config Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Customer Grid index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Category Products index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product Categories index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product Price index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Product EAV index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Stock index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Catalog Rule Product index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Catalog Product Rule index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Catalog Search index is locked by another reindex process. Skipping.
Search Spell-Correction index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended but you can try this?

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

Then run

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: Hi Jeya, Thanks for the quick response. I tried that earlier but didn't regenerate the tables and the same issue persists.

Comment: can you execute this `SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`innodb_locks`;` and see ?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve by reset index, and reindex again

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

Answer (score 0):

similar issue resolved by backup and restore in magento